# Understanding C errno

Tags: c, libc

On my system `errno` defined as:

```
int *    __error(void);
#define errno    (* __error())
```

I understand `errno` is a macro and expands to `* __error()` function:

1. I searched everywhere (source on my system) but I can't find the definition of the `__error()` function, can someone show/explain what would/should be the definition of it?
2. How the expression `errno = 0` works with the above definition (Assigning `0` to a function?)? Does `errno = 0` expands to `* __error() = 0`?

Thanks

Comment: For reference, can you tell us what "my system" is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `__error` function returns a pointer to the `errno` variable for the calling thread. The `errno` macro dereferences that pointer, resulting in an lvalue that can appear on either side of an equals sign.

To answer your questions:

1. The function determines the correct address for the `errno` variable for that specific thread. Each thread gets its own.
2. Yes, it becomes `(* __error()) = 0;` which assigns `0` to that thread's `errno` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this means that somewhere in my OS function `__error()` has a definition as `int * __error() { return &errno; }`, am I right? and the `errno` is `static int errno` in .c file??

Comment: @ManiH.: probably it will be a bit more complicated, the returned `errno` won't be a global, but will come from some kind of thread-local storage (i.e. there's a `errno` instance for each thread, and the `__error()` implementation will retrieve a pointer to the instance relative to the current thread).